# Find string between a starting string and first occurrence of a ending string

Tags: regex, string

From this string:

```
... Descriere: hauser - un motor ars , in urma reviziei 
anuale echipa sosita in statie a constatat ca unul din 
hausere functioneaza cu un singur motor . </p> Alte... <p>
Reparare efectuat... </p>
```

I need to get the string between `Descriere:` and the first occurrence of the `</p>` string.
I tried: `(Descriere: )(.*)(<\/p>)` but it gets the entire string, not stopping at first delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a non-greedy quantifier (`.*?`: note the last `?`). This will capture *as few* characters as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Make it non-greedy by adding a quantifier should work :

```
(Descriere: )(.*?)(<\/p>)
```

or

```
(Descriere: )(.*+)(<\/p>)
```